# WPF Combobox box keeps closing when mouse over the non selected item

Tags: c#, excel, wpf

I have an Excel addin that uses some WPF / XAML to render a Combobox in a grid. When I click on the Combo it drops down the other items but when I mouse down to select the second option in the drop down it closes. I can select other items using the keyboard or mouse scroll wheel when the combo is closed.

The issue only happens on my machine or a HyperV machine hosted by that same machine. The exact version of the code works fine on a remote Azure VM. All 3 are Windows 10.